# Spring security RoleHiearchy doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, roles

I try to add a role hierarchy to my spring Security app I used this configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan (basePackages = "com.medkhelifi.security")
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AffirmativeBased getAccessDecisionManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setDefaultRolePrefix("");
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy());

        WebExpressionVoter webExpressionVoter = new WebExpressionVoter();
        webExpressionVoter.setExpressionHandler(expressionHandler);

        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> voters = new ArrayList<>();

        voters.add(webExpressionVoter);
        return new AffirmativeBased(voters);
    }


    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy (){
        RoleHierarchyImpl roleHierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        roleHierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER");
        return roleHierarchy;
    };

    public JwtSecurityConfig(){
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .accessDecisionManager(getAccessDecisionManager())
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
        //@formatter:on
    }

}
```

The idea is to add ROLE_USER to ROLE_ADMIN hiearchy but it don't work when i try to apply a secured ROLE_USER to one of my request

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public String index(Principal principal){
    return userRepository.findByEmail("admin@gmail.com").toString();
}
```

I get 403 Forbidden error, but when I replace  @Secured("ROLE_USER") by @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") it works very well.

Comment: I assume you have an @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity annotation somewhere?

Comment: @NatFar yes I have in the main SpringBoot Application class '@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)'